# Show table data single in a row

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to know the output in Oracle sql

```
Country              Code
USA                  23, 24, 25, 30
Canada               40, 50, 70
```

Output to be displayed like this

```
Country            Code
USA                 23
USA                 24
USA                 25
USA                 30
Canada              40
Canada              50
Canada              70
```

Comment: Which is used SQL Server version?

Comment: It's for learning purpose. I am using Oracle 11g

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `connect by` with `instr` get `,` group number to level, then use `regexp_substr` get the string.

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   Country varchar(50),
   Code varchar(50)
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES ('USA','23, 24, 25, 30');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Canada','40, 50, 70');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select distinct Country,trim(regexp_substr(Code, '[^,]+', 1, level)) Code
FROM T
connect by instr(Code, ',', 1, level - 1)  > 0
ORDER BY Country desc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/96de88/10/0)**:

```
| COUNTRY | CODE |
|---------|------|
|     USA |   23 |
|     USA |   24 |
|     USA |   25 |
|     USA |   30 |
|  Canada |   40 |
|  Canada |   50 |
|  Canada |   70 |
```

Comment: Is there any other method without using regexp_substr

Comment: @ArunSolomon Why don't you want to use `regexp_substr `?

Comment: I know this method but I want to know is there any other way we can do this.

Comment: I think `REGEXP_SUBSTR` is the easiest way to make it, otherwise you need to use `SUBSTR` in a function to make it.

Comment: Ok. Thanku I got it.